# Use internal Wi-Fi card and USB card for virtualbox

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox

I was able to get a usb Wi-Fi adapter working on virtualbox. However I am no longer able to tether to my laptop's internal Wi-Fi, via `eth0`. How do I allow my OS on virtualbox to see both the USB Wi-Fi interface and recieve internet access via my laptop?

Thank you

Comment: Most hypervisors don't have access to non-USB devices unless hardware visualization is supported.  Does your hardware support it?

Comment: Before I introduced the external wi-fi card, originally, I was able to get internet connection by using my laptop's internet connection. I don't think it supports the ability for virtualbox to use it for wireless, which is not what I want anyway. The "tethering" stopped after introducing the external card, and even when I turn off the USB card, while my laptop has internet via the internal card, virtualbox gets no connection.

Comment: You want to tether your lan connection or connect the Wi-Fi card to the virtualbox, your current question, sort of indicate you want use hardware virtualization to connect the card itself and NOT do a tether.

Comment: I made the edit. Yes I want to tether virtualbox to my laptop's internal card while simultaneously connecting virtualbox to a usb wifi card (I have already connect the usb card to virtualbox )